# Process exited with code 134 - Script execution in VsCode

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, visual-studio-code

I'm reciving this error `Process exited with code 134` when i try to debug a script in VsCode.

If I run the same script without breakpoints it runs normaly.

I'm using node v18.18.1

The script is raw JS, so it exclude libraries errors.

Any Ideias how to get foward with this error?

I've try reboot the sistem, exclude cache and temp files, reinstall node and vscode after a full uninstall.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It may be of additional help if you [raise an issue ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/issues/new). If you do, provide as much detail as possible about how to reproduce the problem, and please ping me here with a link to your issue ticket.